# Beginner Javascript Timer

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Hey guys beginningto get my head around JavaScript slowly, just wondering where I am going wrong in this piece of code.

I want ever two seconds for the 'banner' div to flick between hello and bye.

I am going wrong somewhere are it onlyever says hello (tick is always 0)

Any Help Greatly Appreciated

```
 <html>

<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" >     </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="banner"></div>

<script>

var tick = 0

    $(document).ready(
    setInterval(change(),2000)
    )


    function change(){

    if(tick == 0){
        document.getElementById('banner').innerHTML = "hello"
        tick = 1
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('banner').innerHTML = "bye"
        tick = 0;
    }

    }

</script>

</body>


 </html>
```

Comment: `setInterval(change(),2000);` <-- you are calling `change()` once , and passing its return value to `setInterval()` which is null. Change it to `setInterval(change,2000);`

Comment: This isn't the source of the problem, but in general you should end each statement with `;`, at least until you are very good at JavaScript.

Comment: thanks for the reply, so let me get this straight, change() should be used when I am returning something, and change is used when I am not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `change` function (so that it runs immediately, with the result passed to `setInterval`) instead of passing a reference to the `change` function to the `setInterval()` function (so that `setInterval` can call the `change` function itself at the right times).

Try this (passing a reference to `change` to `setInterval`)

```
setInterval(change,2000)
```

instead of this (calling `change` and passing the result to `setInterval`)

```
setInterval(change(),2000)
```

Heres a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5eLktrdf/

Comment: thanks for the help, so let me get this straight, change() should be used when I am returning something, and change is used when I am not?

Comment: Almost, you use `change()` to call the function and do whatever it is supposed to do. However if you want to pass this function to another (like in this case setInterval)  so that setInterval can call the function whenever it sees fit, you need to give it the function reference and not call it. So therefore we just pass `change` which gives setInterval the possibility to use it (`change()`) later on.